# X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++"

Tags: c++, flutter, visual-studio, dart, windows-11

Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.6)
X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop
development with C++" workload, and include these components:
MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
- If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
C++ CMake tools for Windows
Windows 10 SDK
This is showing when I run flutter doctor

Comment: Did you do what the message said? If not, what exactly is your question?

Comment: This is documented on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-0-installation?view=msvc-170).